Connection between Miketz & Purim and connection between Chanakah & Purim?
In Parshas Mikeitz, Rashi comments that when a king gives over his ring - the one who he gave it to is now second-to-king; as Paroh gave his ring to Yosef. The only other time in Tanach where the Torah (Rashi) brings down a king giving over his ring to somebody else is in the Megilah, where Achashveirosh gave his ring over to Haman. Two Questions:

What is the connection between Parshas Mikeitz and Purim?
Chanakah usually falls out during Parshas Mikeitz (as it does this year); what's the connection between Chanakah and Purim?


https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4344/chanukah-and-miketz

My question is about Mikeitz And Purim!!!

Somebody please reopen my question

If your question is about Mikeitz And Purim, and not Mikeitz and Chanakah, a good first step would be to edit out the Chanakah related parts (for instance, question number 1).

https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/megillat-ester-and-the-yosef-story-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

@TamirEvan - my mistake! I meant to write Purim!
