Connection between Miketz & Purim and connection between Chanukah & Purim?
(Please don't close this question - It's NOT A DUPLICATE!)
Connection between Miketz & Purim and connection between Chanakah & Purim? [duplicate]
In Parshas Miketz, Rashi comments that when a king gives over his ring - the one who he gave it to is now second-to-king; as Paroh gave his ring to Yosef. The only other time in Tanach where the Torah (Rashi) brings down a king giving over his ring to somebody else is in the Megilah, where Achashveirosh gave his ring over to Haman. Two questions:

What is the connection between Parshas Mikeitz and Chanukah?
Chanukah usually falls out during Parshas Mikeitz (as it does this year); What's the connection between Chanukah and Purim?


According to R' Schiffman the events of Chanukkah ended when because of the Syrian Greek infighting, one of the sides made a treaty with the Chashmonaim and gave them independence over 25 years afterwards. But the original liberation of the Temple was completely wiped out in a few years.

@YDJ Maybe you should point that comment at the original of this question.

Is your first question about Mikeitz and Chanukah (as the body of the question says) or about Miketz and Purim (as the title suggests)?

@Banana https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/146593/connection-between-miketz-purim-and-connection-between-chanakah-purim#comment491462_146593
